# What happens for hardware Interrupts in non-preemptive scheduling?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

In non-preemptive scheduling, the running process cant be interrupted  .But what will when the CPU receive a hardware interrupt such as the an interrupt from the printer indicating that the current job has been completed ? Does the CPU will preempt the current running process and handles the interrupt ( run its interrupt service routine ) or this interrupt will be stored and then handled when the current running process leaves the CPU ?

Answer (score 1):

In a non-preemptive scheduler, the running process cannot be interrupted by **another process**.  The running process **can** be interrupted by hardware interrupts.